# Refresh a KendoUI Grid that is created via Table (without a data source)

Tags: kendo-ui

As explained here:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/introduction

There are two primary ways to create a Kendo UI Grid:

From an empty div element. In this case all the Grid settings are provided in the initialization script statement.
From an existing HTML table element. In this case some of the Grid settings can be inferred from the table structure and elements' HTML attributes.

Each way have it's pros and cons, in my eyes, having it done via an html table, is much easier, because you write much less java script, and it is much more easier to make changes.

I just pass in a list of strongly type objects to a razor view, create a table and with 5 lines of JS we have a Kendo Grid.

Problem is when i click a line in the grid, i open a jquery dialog to add data to the table, when user submits a valid of form (in the dialog), the DB gets updated but i can not seem to find a way to update the grid. Besides going back to page 1 with the default number of items per page.
I would like to find a way to refresh the grid in the same manner i would if i would create it using a data source. (see commented code below)

```
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    success: function(data) {                           

                            $('#dialog').dialog('close');

                            //TODO - won't work, i have to redirect back to page 1 and default items per page
                                            //$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                            //$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
                            window.location.href = $('#link-site-root').val() + "/Administration/DivSegParmMap";

                        }

                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert('Failed to get response from ValidateJqueryDialog ajax call.');
                    }
                });


            });
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Also i have been happily using stackoverflow for many years, learned a lot, and i want to finally help others, i would need to get some vote ups for my question if you think it's a good one. Thanks!